# expressjs passport login error

Tags: express, passport.js

i try to use passport with expressjs. the req.login function within passport.authenticate function trigger an error, i really don't know what i do wrong.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, function (username, password, done) {

    userModel.findOne({ 'email': username }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown email adress ' + username }); }
        user.comparePassword(password, function (err, isMatch) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            if (isMatch) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
            }
        });
    });
}));

passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(401, "Invalid authentication");
            }

            if (!user) {
                return res.send(401, info.message);
            }

            req.login(user, function (err) {
                //console.log(user);
                console.log(err);
                if (err) {
                    return res.send(401, "Invalid authentication4");
                }
                return res.send(200, res);
            });
        })(req, res, next);
```

The browser show me the alert Invalid authentication4, the error is triggers in req.login function. On shell console.log(err) who me a message undefined [TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON]

Comment: What does the `err` that's triggering the response say?

Comment: undefined [TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON]

Comment: Try `console.log(err.stack)` to get a stack trace, perhaps that gives you a clue where the error is thrown.

Comment: get TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined

Comment: Bah, try `console.trace()` instead of `console.log(...)`.

Comment: at D:\nodejs_example\app_old\routes\signin.js:29:25
at D:\nodejs_example\app_old\node_modules\passport\lib\passport\http\request.js:46:7
at pass (D:\nodejs_example\app_old\node_modules\passport\lib\passport\index.js:271:43)
at D:\nodejs_example\app_old\node_modules\passport\lib\passport\index.js:279:36
at passport.use.LocalStrategy.usernameField (D:\nodejs_example\app_old\models\pass.js:7:5)
at pass (D:\nodejs_example\app_old\node_modules\passport\lib\passport\index.js:279:7)
at Passport.serializeUser (D:\nodejs_example\app_old\node_modules\passport\lib\passport\index.js:283:5)

Comment: Can you post (as part of your question) your implementation of `passport.serializeUser` and `passport.deserializeUser`?